# NSUserDefaults crashes with setInteger

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I used this part of code in my Application for a while and it worked as expected. But now, it crashes on the line with setInteger:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int selEvent = [defaults integerForKey:@"selected_event"];
/*
 * Do Something with selEvent
 * New ID is in NSNumber event_id
 */
[defaults setInteger:[event_id intValue] forKey:@"selected_event"]; //Crashes on this line
[defaults synchronize];
```

Working in Xcode 4.5.1 and iPad 6.0 Simulator.

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Whats the cause of my problem?

Comment: How and were you create event_id (is is in the same method you save it to defaults or not)? Also, do you use ARC in your project?

Comment: using arc, event_id is created in the same way as before. It has a valid value, if I stop the programm right before setInteger: (the same as before)

Comment: The same code works fine on my iPad 6.0 Simulator.The difference is that I'm not using arc.

Comment: If you change "setInteger:[event_id intValue]" to "setInteger:0", does it still crash?

Comment: Could you post a crash log please? I'm curious whether the crash is actually from the -setInteger: call, or somewhere else in your program that's triggered by it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my Problem:

```
NSDictionary *defaultUserDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"selected_event",
                                     nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultUserDefaults];
```

This worked before with setInteger:

Changed all setIntegers with setObject .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I traced it back to something else:

I stored integers in NSUserDefaults just fine with code like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:_currentBannerIndex forKey:@"currentBannerIndex"];
```

After a certain period it crashed at the same point, writing the same value.
The cause was that after this period I registered for changes in the NSUserdefaults with code like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(userDefaultsChanged) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

This was done in an importer at initialization. After the importer was deallocaed, a new write to the user defaults was triggering the observer for an object that was gone. Boom. Crash.

The solution was of course to remove the observer in the dealloc of my importer.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would say problem is at `[event_id intValue]`

`event_id` is `NSString` & its getting released and hence this error is occurring.

Answer (score -1):

```
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"KeyName"];
```